# API for creating behaviour in cloudfront

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

I have created a CloudFront Distribution through the console , Am trying to create a origin and behaviour in that distribution using boto3

I cant find any api to create origin and  behaviour in cloudfront. I have checked the boto3 documentaion.

Is there any boto 3 api to create those in cloudfront?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: They are not seperate entities, you need to use [update_distribution](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#CloudFront.Client.update_distribution)

Comment: @jordanm any chance you could provide an example snippet of how to create a behavior with that method?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is like 9 months too little too late, but here is how you'd update the cloudfront distribution - which I know isn't the question... let me get there.

```
import boto3
# get the cloudfront distribution id
Id = "*************"
# create a cloudfront instance
cloudfront = boto3.client("cloudfront")
# get the json response for the configuration of the distribution
distribution = cloudfront.get_distribution_config(Id=Id)
# get the json configuration for the distribution
distribution_data = distribution["DistributionConfig"]
# change the data
for e in distribution_data["CacheBehaviors"]["Items"]:
    if "behavior_name" in e["PathPattern"]:
        e["PathPattern"] = "/new_behavior_name/*"


# send data
cloudfront.update_distribution(Id=Id, DistributionConfig=distribution_data, IfMatch=distribution["ETag"])
```

I haven't tested this, but it'd stand for me to reason, that to add a behavior, you would just have to add an origin

```
distribution_data["Origins"]
```

and your additional items into the

```
distribution_data["CacheBehaviors"]["Items"]
```

, configured the same way as the others, of course. Then, send the data in an update request.

You can find how to configure both the origin and the cache behaviors in the documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront/client/update_distribution.html).